# What's the Purpose of "MAX(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(X),1,DATALENGTH(CONVERT(X))*1 or 0))" in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I have inherited a stored procedure which has code like the following. It's sort of a poor-man's PIVOT, I think (has to run on SQL Server 2000).

```
SELECT
    [TheDate] = MAX(
                substring(
                    CONVERT(VarChar(100), thedate, 101), 
                    1, 
                    datalength(CONVERT(VarChar(100), thedate, 101)) * 
                        ( CASE index WHEN 123 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ))),
    [Scaled] = MAX(
                substring(
                    CONVERT(VarChar(100), Scaled), 
                    1, 
                    datalength(CONVERT(VarChar(100), Scaled)) * 
                        ( CASE index WHEN 123 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ))),
    [Value] = MAX(
                substring(
                    CONVERT(VarChar(100), [Value]), 
                    1, 
                    datalength(CONVERT(VarChar(100), [Value])) * 
                        ( CASE index WHEN 123 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ))),
-- Repeat for other values of "index"
GROUP BY other columns
```

Has anyone seen this construct before? Not the "pivot" stuff, but rather the

```
MAX(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(X),1,DATALENGTH(CONVERT(X))*1 or 0))
```

Why not just use

```
MAX(CASE index WHEN 123 THEN [Value] ELSE NULL END)
```

?

Comment: Nice to see you have some faith in your predecessor's sanity.

Comment: The equivalent would be `MAX(CASE index WHEN 123 THEN left([Value],100) ELSE '' END)` I suspect there is no good reason for using this construct.

Comment: Back in the day, I remember CASE queries being VERY SLOW, especially when there were more than one of them in a single query. Perhaps the multiple SUBSTRINGs and CONVERTs were somehow faster. Maybe?

Comment: Poor man's PIVOT?  PIVOT isn't widely supported (SQL Server 2005+, Oracle 11g+ - haven't seen such for PostgreSQL, DB2 likely does...).  The above is more supported than PIVOT...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting quote

> It's sort of a poor-man's PIVOT

I happen to know that the PIVOT operator is the emperor's new clothes on top of multiple CASE statements. In fact that is how the query plan appears.  So there is more than one way to look at it.

Martin's use of LEFT(, length) is the shortcut for doing a convert to a particular length, since LEFT (and RIGHT) implicitly converts the first argument.
*There is one case where it won't work though, for the CONVERT(varchar, date, 101) which is a specific format.*

> DATALENGTH(CONVERT(X))*1 or 0)

This may have been an attempt to size the resultant columns based on the maximum length in the columns, but clearly this is not the right code (if that is the purpose).

```
MAX(CASE index WHEN 123 THEN [Value] ELSE NULL)
```

Looking much better. "index" is a keyword so if you copied your snippet from working code, I would be surprised. Maybe it works in 2000?
Some tips:

1. brackets around "index"
2. missing "end" for case
3. missing CONVERT (the data does not seem to be varchar, so you need to convert)
4. the original returns '' not NULL when it is not 123

   MAX(CASE [index] WHEN 123 THEN CONVERT(varchar(100), [Value], 101) ELSE '' END)

*(I threw in the 101 for [value] to be consistent with the date format. It has no effect on numerics)*

Comment: Last time I tested, my PIVOT statement was a second slower than the aggregate/CASE equivalent.

Comment: @OMG - AFAIK, it internally optimizes to the same plan, so unless you have introduced some minor nuances to the query, they should come up the same. However with all tests, there are at least 10 other factors in play (disk I/O, ram, buffer, plan cache, the roll of the dice etc) so as long as the "second" is within some margin of error, I would ignore it.

Comment: @cyberwiki: "index" was a word chosen for obfuscation. You might be right about conversion being one of the reasons. The underlying table was changed. The new table is much more "type-safe". Date/times are actually `datetime`, for instance, while they were just varchar in the original. Maybe some of this was actually needed for the original table.